# How to underline text in a h2 but not other elements

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML block similar to the following:

```
<h2><span class="numbers">1.1 </span>header text</h2>
```

NOTE: I didn't write the HTML, so I can't change that, all I can do is add some CSS.

I want to underline the text "header text", but not the 1.1.

Using CSS, if I do

```
h2 {text-decoration: underline;}
```

The entire line is underlined, and since I can't override the text-decoration below h2, I am at a loss as to how to handle this.

(Here is the code of this issue

```css
h2   { text-decoration: underline; }
span { text-decoration: none;      }
```

```html
<h2><span class=numbers>1.2 </span>header text</h2>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's something you can't achieve with CSS alone. "Text decorations are drawn across descendant text elements. This means that if an element specifies a text decoration, then a child element can't remove the decoration" [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Comment: @Terry not all the descendants. Some of them can stop the underline propagation like inline-block elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif Don't shoot the messenger: just copy pasta from MDN docs.

Comment: Thanks @JDawwgy, while your solution may not actually work for me since I dont for sure know the color of any given background where it lives, it is a pretty slick answer.  I'm going to mark your answer as the solution.    The answer by Deepak-Kamat is valid as well and might actually be preferred in some situations, but I think changing the color of the underline is slightly less potentially impactful than changing the background and padding of the span. (though as I said, there are cases where that might be the better solution).

Comment: you are not obliged to mark any solution as accepted if they don't work for you. By the way, check the duplicate to get a solution where you don't need to set any color and it works with any background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. The numbers are still technically underlined but if its on a white background you can make their underline match the background to appear as though it isn't underlined

```css
h2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.numbers {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2><span class="numbers">1.1 </span>header text</h2>
```

Comment: wow! I thought this was not even possible to achieve with `text-decoration`..  this is brilliant, never explored this `text-decoration-color` property haha!

Comment: not bad at all, but `h2 span {...` should be enough, no ?

Comment: Nice trick, but this also means it will only work against a solid color background... and you need to know the background color which this text is being rendered on top of :) but if OP is using a solid color background of known color, this is quite a smart way.

Comment: @Terry if the OP knows the HTML isn't changing ever, for whatever reason, I would like to believe its surrounding isn't going to change that often either., that's definitely a trade-off that has to be done.

Comment: @MisterJojo your correct, I could have used the `h2 span` I updated it to just be the class name `.numbers` used as the selector.

@Terry Yes this is a bit of a workaround solution that will only work on a solid color background

Comment: Sadly, I don't for sure know that the HTML is never changing, so I know whatever I do will induce potential problems in the future if something does change... but it's what I have to work with. :(

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible to do with `text-decoration` (UPDATE: It is possible to achieve this with `just text-decoration`), if you are aiming to just have an underline, which can be achieved by using `border-bottom` then you can do something like this

```
h2 {
  border-bottom:2px solid; 
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  display: inline; 
  background-color: #fff; 
  padding: 3px 0;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/DeepakKamat/eqjsg0nL/

Use background color on the span and give it a vertical padding to hide the border on its parent element.

Comment: Thanks, I did think of this, but was hoping for something more... elegant?  it feels like this shouldn't be this hard and I was hoping that I was simply missing something.  for all of my own html I've learned long ago to put everything that I might someday want to format into it's own element with a usefull class/id so I can call it out later.